# mySQl connect with random user value

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to connect to a sql database with the following code line below:

```
mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
```

When i edit the localhost to something else it gives an error. When i edit the password argument to something else it gives an error. This is not unexcepted, but when i edit the username which is root it does not give a error. Why does not it give a error on the username. It seems like i can connect with any username. Have i done anything wrong ?

Comment: are you able to execute queries with **any** username?

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: As a side node: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: @ZnArK: That much should be obvious from the tags and the PHP functions...

Comment: Ok, Thx for help @Truth. Would you recommend using PDO instead of MySQLi ?

Comment: @Ukjent: PDO, as it works with more database types (not just MySQL but more).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will most likely be able to "connect" but won't be able to actually do anything as far as run a query. If you run

```
SELECT * FROM mysql.user
```

you will probably see a row that looks something like this:

```
Host       User    Password    Select_priv ...
localhost  ''      ''          N
```

The database has an empty user/password record with no privileges for any table. Therefore, if you connect with a user that does not exist (password will have to be empty, otherwise you will get an access error) you will actually be able to connect but not actually do anything